# Angular - condition, transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've written a sample directive with a conditional content (component.html):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">{{title}}</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <p ng-show="loadingVisible()" class="text-center">Loading...</p>

    <div ng-show="!loadingVisible()" ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

Directive code (component.js):

```
app.directive('component', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        transclude : true,
        replace : true,
        templateUrl : 'component.html',
        require : '^title',
        scope : {
            title : '@',
            loadingVisible : '&'
        },
        controller : [ '$scope', function ($scope) {
            if (!$scope.loadingVisible) {
                $scope.loadingVisible = function () {
                    return false;
                };
            }
        } ]
    };
});
```

The main use of this directive is something like this (sample.html):

```
<div component title="Title">
    <div id="t"></div>
</div>
```

And the controller code (sample.js):

```
app.directive('sample', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'sample.html',
            controller: [ '$scope', function ($scope) {
                $('#id');
        } ]
    };
});
```

0
The problem is that the div aquired by using jQuery selector isn't visible. I guess it's because the loadingVisible method (conditional content) hides that div in the construction phase. So when the sample directive tries to get it it fails. Am I doing something wrong? What's the coorect resolution of this problem? Or maybe my knowledge of directives is wrong?

I'll appreciate any help :)

Comment: where does the ```sample``` directive actually get used? You have ```sample``` declared as an attribute directive, but where are you using it?

also, in the current state of your ```component``` directive, it's is requiring the controller from another directive called ```title``` via the ```require: '^title'``` line. Is there another ```title``` directive somewhere?

Comment: Sample directive goes in some routed view and it is used like this: <div sample></div>. I used require to show that attribute title is required. Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: I think you're getting confused. you use ```require``` in a directive when you want to pull in the controller from another directive (in this case, a parent directive). require has nothing to do with your isolate-scoped attributes (i.e. title and loadingVisible).

Comment: I removed the `require` property. It didn't solve my problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to interact with the DOM (or the directive element itself), you'll want to define a `link` function. The `link` function gets fired after angular compiles your directive and gives you access to the directives `scope`, the `element` itself, and any `attributes` on the directive. so, something like:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
  /* interact with elem and/or scope here */
}
```

<strike>I'm still a little unclear about what your directive is trying to accomplish though, so it's tough to provide much more help. Any additional details?</strike>

so if you want to ensure that a title is specified, you can just check for the presence of the title scope var when the directive gets linked, then throw an error if it's not there.

also, is there any reason `loadingVisible` needs to be an expression? (using '&' syntax). If you just need to show/hide content based on this value, you could just do a normal one-way '@' binding. so overall, something like:

```
app.directive('component', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        transclude : true,
        replace : true,
        templateUrl : 'component.html',
        scope : {
            title : '@',
            loadingVisible : '@'
        },
        link : function (scope, elem, attrs) {

          if (!scope.title) {
            throw 'must specify a title!';
          }
          if (!attrs.loadingVisible) {
              scope.loadingVisible = false;
          }
        }
    };
});
```

If you need to get access to any of your transcluded content, you can use the elem value that gets injected into your link function, like so:

```
elem.find('#a');
```

an (updated) working plnkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/JVZjQAG8gGhcV2tz1ImK/preview

Comment: I want a component which is a panel with given title and dynamic inside content. When any outside directive uses this directive it *must* define panel title and *can* define loadingVisible function. This function almost always checks if the model is in the scope (model is not in scope when using for instance $http.get in the controller method). I also want to add default loadingVisible method implementation which return false, so there will be no loading text in the panel and other directives doesn't have to be modified.

Comment: Ok. I know that it works but adding something like: `$('#a').html("dddd");` to the controller causes a problem...

Comment: Of course *a* is a div inside a component: `<div component ...><div id="a"></div></div>`.

Comment: Update: I want to get this element in "child" component, in its controller. Not in component link method :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that directive structure is like this:

```
  <div component>
    <div id="a"></div>
  </div>
```

The directive is used somewhere like this:

asd

The test directive uses a "a" element in its controller (or link) function. The problem is that the test controller code is run before the div is transcluded and it cannot see the content :/ A simple workaround is that the component should be before the test directive. Do you have any other solutions to this problem?